# Colocar imagen PDF xhtml2pdf en produccion

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

Saludos tengo un proyecto en Django el cual esta en produccion mediante Apache y WSGI en Centos 7, lo cual funciona bien menos por la imagen en un PDF, la misma nose visualiza este PDF genero mediante **xhtml2pdf** mi codigo con el que genero mi PDF es:

```
def render_facturaelectronica(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    path = 'media/temp_ride/ride.pdf'
    PATH_COMPLETO =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),path)
    result2= open(PATH_COMPLETO, 'wb')
    pdf2 = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result2)
    if not pdf2.err:
        print "Generado RIDE sin errores"
    return None
```

Como comentaba genera sin errores pero la imagen nose visualiza en el template tengo:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8/ISO-8859-1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>{{ clave_acceso }}</title>
</head>
<style>
td {
    font-family: TimesNewRoman,Times New Roman,Times,Baskerville,Georgia,serif;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <img src="static/logo.jpg"  width="400" height="100"  alt="RGManagementcorp">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <strong>{{ empresa }}</strong><br>
            <strong>Dirección Matriz: </strong><br>{{ direc_empresa }}<br>
            <strong>Teléfono: </strong><br>{{ telefono_empresa }}<br>
            <strong>OBLIGADO A LLEVAR CONTABILIDAD</strong><br>{{ obligado_contabilidad }}<br>
        </td>
        <td colspan="4">
             <b>R.U.C.:</b> <br>{{ ruc_empresa }}<br>
            <b>FACTURA:</b><br>{{ numero_factura }}<br>
            <b>NÚMERO DE AUTORIZACIÓN:</b><br>{{ numero_autorizacion }}<br>
            <b>FECHA Y HORA DE AUTORIZACIÓN:</b><br>{{ fec_autorizacion }}<br>
            <b>AMBIENTE:</b><br>{{ ambiente }}<br>
            <b>EMISIÓN:</b><br>NORMAL <br>
            <b>CLAVE DE ACCESO:</b><br>{{ clave_acceso }}<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

he intentado distintas opciones como

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static 'logo.jpg' %}">
```

tambien :

```
<img src="../static/logo.jpg">
```

ó:

```
 <img src="/static/logo.jpg">
```

sin resultados no sale ningun error tan solo no se ve la imagen en el PDF.

Gracias cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: La imagen debe ser generada con base64.

Prueba convirtiendo la imagen a base64 .

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar esto:
[xhtml2pdf - Recursos](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django)

O convertir la imagen a base64.